# How to give image percent height of window

Tags: html, css

I got a logotype in my header that i want to be 10% of the window height.

```
<header style="float: left; height: auto; width: 100%;">
<img src="..." style="float: left; height: 10%;" />
</header>
```

this will result in my image not changing size at all, how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's a good way, but in my css i have :

```
html{
   height:100%;
}

body{
   height:100%;
}
```

edit : so your header heigth should be 10% of body, and your image 100% of your header....

```
<header style="float: left; height: 10%; width: 100%;>
     <img src='...' style="float: left; height: 100%;" />
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set the Header to have a height of a 10% from the _parent element (it could even be that the parent be the `<body>` element).

Then you make the img to fit 100% of the  height.

So for something like

```
<body>
<header>
<img src="" />
</header>
</body>
```

You may have:

```
body {
height: 100%;
}

header {
height: 10%;
}

img {
height: 100%;
}
```

Just an idea, for sure. If you think about it, you can find a clever solution based on this, but clever than this easy approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can make it with some jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    logotypeHeight();
    function logotypeHeight() {
        var height = $('window').height();
        $('header img').css('height', (height/100) * 10);
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        logotypeHeight();
    });

});
```

greetings Timotheus